# No result from MongoDB / MongoJS query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I'm trying to query my DB for users, but nothing happens when I try.

Here is my code to query the DB:

```
console.log("before db.user");
db.user.find({steamid: userSteamId}, function(err, user){
  if(err || !user){
    console.log("No account found, prompt for tradelink to create acct");
    //createUser(userSteamId, tradelink);
  } else user.forEach( function(tradelink){
      console.log(tradelink);
    });
});
console.log("after db.user");
```

Here is the console output:

```
before db.user
after db.user
```

There are no error messages, and neither the if, nor the else console.log statements are echoed to the console. What's wrong here, and is there any way I can see the responses from my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to log user before iterating it. it might be empty in that case your query is wrong or there is no matching data in the database.